# startswith ends with and containing in Apache free marker

Tags: freemarker, data-processing

How to check whether particular `string` `starts with` hello or `ends with` Hello or `contains` hello in 
`apache free marker`. is there any predefined `function` available

```
HelloIamShruti
IamShrutiHello
ShrutiHelloSharma
```

If i want to check `starts with "Hello" first string should be returned`
If i want to check `ends with "Hello" second string should be returned`
If i want to check `contains  "Hello" last string should be returned`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Freemarker methods available for your requests are:

- starts_with, ex. `"redblue"?starts_with("red")` will return true.
- ends_with, ex. `"redblue"?ends_with("red")` will return false.
- contains, ex. `<#if "piceous"?contains("ice")>It contains "ice"</#if>` will show the message

When you want the word to be contained but not in the start or the end, just add an if condition to check if `starts_with` and `ends_with` result to false.

Comment: thanks Fotiou. Actually starts with and ends with returns true/ false. I have to return redblue as per above example

Comment: @ShrutiSharma There's no shorthand for that, you have to use `#if` then. Or, you can write a macro to do this if this is needed very often.